# Geometry (Finding angle $x$)

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

So everybody was given this question: [image]

in the recent new zealand mathematics exam yesterday (for students aged 14-15), and most if not everybody was stumped by it.

How would you solve this?

Comment: First thing to figure out is, is it possible that a kite can fit in a square at an oblique angle.  If not then $FG = GH = \frac 12 DG$ and $\angle FGD = 60$ and $\angle DGB = 30$ and $\angle GDB=(180 -30)/2 = 75$ so $\angle DBE = 75 + 75 = 150$.  But is it possible that $FG \ne GH$?  That needs to be figured out first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean that $B$ and $G$ they are mid-points of $FH$ and $AC$ respectively.

Since $FG=\frac{1}{2}BG= \frac{1}{2}DG,$ we obtain:
$$\measuredangle DGB=\measuredangle FDG=30^{\circ}.$$
Thus, $$\measuredangle DBE=2\measuredangle DBG=2\cdot75^{\circ}=150^{\circ}.$$

Comment: How do you conclude DGB is 30 degrees?

Comment: @dydxx I added something. See now.

Comment: Shouldn't that mean 2*60 = 120?

Comment: No! Because $\measuredangle GDB=75^{\circ}\neq90^{\circ}.$.

Comment: How do you know $FG = \frac 12 BG$.  I.e. how do you know a kite must fit in symmetrically?

Comment: @fleablood I agree with you. The given is not full.

Comment: A slightly more interesting problem is to start with $x=150^\circ$, $DG=EG$, and $FG=HG$, and prove that $\measuredangle DGE=60^{\circ}$. With trigonometry, this is easy since $\tan 60^\circ +\tan 15^\circ=2$. But a purely geometric proof, with ruler and straightedge only, might take a bit longer.

Comment: I think the problem needs more information to be given to be rigorously solved. Being given that G is the midpoint of FH is sufficient. Right now, it's not possible to conclude that BG is a line of symmetry for the whole figure, and that's crucial.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: Surely someone can trig-chase this.  Suppose $\angle FGB=\theta \ne 90$ then, we can using trig express the lengths of $DF, FG, GH, HE$ etc. in terms of angles and knowing that $AF = FH = HC = AC$ while $BG = DG = GE$ can we not conclude those are only consistant if $\theta = 90$.  I mean, *I*'m not going to do it, but... can't it be done.

Comment: Oh, wait.  The "top" of a kite, can be anything independent of a the bottom. So just as we can fit a symmetric kite into squares or rectangles of any dimension, we can stick asymmetic kits into squares or rectiangles of nearly any dimensions (some restrictions of course).  So we can fit an assymetrical kite into a square.  Just stick it into a rectangle and "pop" the top of the kite out until the sides of the rectangle are equal.... So no, we do not have enough information.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information.  If we assume $G$ is the midpoint of $FH$ or if we assume the kite is symmetrically aligned with the square so that line $DE$ is parallel with $FH$ then by Michael Rozenberg's and Deepak's deleted answer we can conclude that the angle is $150$.

But if the kite is inserted into the square at an angle so that $G$ is not the midpoint and $DE$ is not parallel, we can not conclude anything.  Suppose we place point $B$ on line $AC$ slightly to the left of $G$ on line $FH$.  There will be one pair of points $D,E$ so that $BG= DG= EF$, but those might not forma a kite if $BD \ne BE$.  However but sliding $B,G$ to the left or right we will force point $D$ lower or higher and point $E$ higher or lower, and line $DB$ longer or shorter and line $BE$ shorter or longer.  The will be one precise point where $DB = BE$ and an assymetric kite was placed in the square.

There are several such kites depending on how "askance" points $B$ and $G$ are from each other.  But they will all form angles $DBE$ that are $\ge 150$, if I am not mistaken[$*$], with $BDE = 150$ precisely at the one symmetrical embedded kite.

Somehow, I suspect the original problem either indicated the kite was inserted symmetrically, or it was assumed.

[$*$] A big "if".  But I'm pretty sure the wider "askew" the kite is aligned, the larger angle $DBE$ will be.